# Decimal point number free text search TSQL

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, decimal-point

How can we search in SQL Server using fulltext search decimal point numbers more accurately?

For instance

```
select ... where contains(field, '5')
```

shows results which contains extra rows with 3.5 2.5 and so on.

I need to exclude these results.

How to tell SQL Server that "." is part of the word in case of numbers?

Comment: Full-text search is a **word-based** search mechanism - it doesn't match single characters and/or numbers ....

Comment: Marc is right, however SQL Server does some number identification and should be able to handle your scenario. I've confirmed this with my own SQL instance and I don't run into the same problem as you. What language are you using for full text (English, Neutral, etc.)? Are you using a custom stoplist or custom word breakers?

Answer (score 0):

`Like` over Free Text Search results can improve accuracy for known patterns.

```
Select *
From [Free Text Search results]
Where [Text] Like '%[^0-9.,]5[^0-9]%' --< Not 25, not 2.5, not 52
```